# Validation laravel comparar 2 campos para não repetir no banco de dados?

Tags: php, laravel, validação, laravel-5.5

Preciso de um se para verificar 2 valores do cadastro e 2 do banco, se ambos forem iguais não devera ocorrer o cadastro.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <form action="adiciona" method="post"  >
      <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">

      <input type="hidden" 
      name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />

      <label>Solicitação:</label>
      <select name="Cadastro_idCadastro" lass="js-data-example-ajax">
            @foreach($cadastro as $c)
            <option value="{{$c->idCadastro}}">{{$c->idCadastro}}</option>
            @endforeach
      </select><br></br>
      <label>Usúario:</label>
      <select name="users_id" lass="js-data-example-ajax">
            @foreach($user as $c)
            <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
      </select><br></br>

      <label>Aprovador:</label>
      <select name="Aprovado_idaprovado" lass="js-data-example-ajax">
            @foreach($aprovar as $c)
            <option value="{{$c->idaprovado}}">{{$c->descaprovado}}</option>
            @endforeach
      </select><br></br>

      <button type="submit" class="btn 
        btn-primary btn-block">Adicionar Aprovador</button>
    </form>
```

---

```
public function adiciona()
{
    Aprovadores::create(Request::all());    
    return redirect()->action('AprovadoresController@novo');
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro? só o código ficou vago.

Comment: desculpe, 
Preciso de um se para verificar 2 valores do cadastro e 2 do banco, se ambos forem iguais não devera ocorrer o cadastro.

meu controller

Aprovadores::create(Request::all());

return redirect() ->action('AprovadoresController@novo');

Comment: seguinte quais valores não pode ser repetidos se pode colocar a tabela na sua pergunta?

Comment: idCadastro e id do usuario.

Comment: me passa a tabela `Aprovadores` (não se deve fazer aquele tipo de insert também?

Comment: idAp,   Cadastro_ipCadatro, users_id,  Aprovado_idaprovado

Comment: (não se deve fazer aquele tipo de insert também?) não entendi

Comment: estava testando faço insert com create(Resquest)

Comment: (não se deve fazer aquele tipo de insert também?)  estipule sempre os campos que são inseridos nunca deixe com que a responsabilidade fique para o tabela isso pode ocasionar problemas futuros!, sem delongas coloque a sua tabela para que eu entenda o que deseja fazer! ta meio vago.

Comment: não sei usar stack over direito, vc tem skype?

Comment: então está na hora de aprender amigo, coloque na sua pergunta o layout da tabela e explique a sua duvida melhor eu posso te ajudar por aqui.

Comment: certo, preciso usar validation para não deixar salvar dois compos iguais para não duplicar, preciso pegar 2 campos no banco e comparar com dois campos do formulário, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation ESTOU TENTANDO ACHAR, MAIS AINDA NADA

Comment: acho que nao precisa colocar tabela.

Comment: era bom colocar a tabela

Comment: veja ai se atende.

Comment: o cadastro_idcadastro users_id, ambos só pode ter uma vez no banco

Comment: versao do laravel?

Comment: laravel 5.5 ta no titulo rsrs

Comment: coloque na tag vai aprendendo.

Comment: Que tag ? ai vc me apertou.

Answer (score 1):

A sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas, acredito que seja uma validação desse tipo, onde os dois campos tem que ser únicos na tabela, abaixo um exemplo minimo de como fazer isso:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class  {

    public function adiciona(Request $request)
    {
        $cadastro_idcadastro = $request->Cadastro_idCadastro;
        $users_id = $request->users_id;

        $request->validate([
            'cadastro_idcadastro' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('aprovadores')->where(function ($query)
                use ($cadastro_idcadastro, $users_id)
                {
                      return $query->where('cadastro_idcadastro', $cadastro_idcadastro)
                                   ->where('users_id', $users_id);
                }),
            ]
        ]);
        // se passar para essas linha os dados são válidos.

        Aprovadores::create(Request::all());    
        return redirect()->action('AprovadoresController@novo');
    }

}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart

Comment: ótimo, posso colocar dentro da AprovadoresRequest ou precisar ficar dentro do método ?

Comment: qualquer uma das duas soluções se colocar no FormRequest não precisa colocar no método e vice versa! claro `AprovadoresRequest`  tem que estár no lugar do Request $request para dar certo.

Comment: deu esse erro ("Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$cadastro_idcadastro")

Comment: @Vagner é Cadastro_idCadastro igual está no formulário.

Comment: @Vagner precisa também rapa dar uma lida na documentação

Comment: tinha tentado Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$Cadastro_idCadastro"

Comment: Infelizmente o problema é que você não mostra o local certinho, eu não sei como te ajudar mais @Vagner é complicado quando um fala alemão e o outro fala brasileiro... entende!

Comment: coloquei igual do formulário ficou com mesmo erro.

Comment: @Vagner uma coisa que já está tudo errado, suas variaveis umas são maiusculos e outras minusculo uma bagunça geral, não pode, tem que ter um padrão, geralmente tudo minusculo e nomes curtos no máximo com underscore, entendeu ...

Comment: E eu também não sei a realidade do seu código @Vagner

Comment: entendo, vou me organizar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado! ajudou muito.